# MySql: Set limit for duplicate column

Tags: sql, mysql

OK I have a column on my table called style_number. There can be duplicates of style_number. I want to select everything, but only up to 3 for each style number.

So for example if there are 4 rows that have a style_number = "style 7" only 3 of those 4 would be selected (doesn't matter which 3, any 3).

Does this make sense?

How can I do that?

Thanks!!

Note: I am using 4.1.22

EDIT:
To clear some confusion. I need all the other columns as well, and I need more than just "style 7" or I could easily limit to 3. but for example if this where my table:

style_number | price | stone_count

```
"style 7" | 300 | 2
"style 7" | 400 | 3
"style 7" | 500 | 4
"style 7" | 600 | 5
"style 8" | 200| 1
"style 8" | 300 | 2
```

I would get this as a result:

```
"style 7" | 300 | 2
"style 7" | 400 | 3
"style 7" | 500 | 4
"style 8" | 200| 1
"style 8" | 300 | 2
```

Does that make better sense?

Comment: can you show us your query as it stands? i'd like to see the where clause, if any.

Comment: Are you only interested in the style_number value, or the related columns in the table with this criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a MySQL developer, but I think that this will give you what you want. No promises on performance though :)

```
SELECT
     T1.id,
     T1.style_number,
     T1.col1,
     T1.col2,
     ...
FROM
     My_Table T1
WHERE
     (
          SELECT
               COUNT(*)
          FROM
               My_Table T2
          WHERE
               T2.style_number = T1.style_number AND
               T2.id < T1.id
     ) < 3
```

Comment: I think this is the closest thing so far to what I need. Unfortunately I am getting this error: #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'.. I don't think I can use LIMIT in a subquery.

Comment: I just edited it and put a different solution in, which will hopefully work in MySQL (works in SQL Server and I think it's ANSI compliant). Again, can't make any promises on performance though.

Comment: Since you didn't care which three are returned I decided to return the three with the lowest id values. The query essentially says, "Give me all of the rows where the number of rows with the same style_number and a lower id is less than 3."  So, if you have id values of 1, 3, 5, and 7 with the same style, the subqueries will return (in order) 1, 2, 3, and 4, so only the first three id values will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE style_number = "style 7" LIMIT 3
```

This will limit the result set to a maximum of 3 rows, whichever 3 the database engine finds first. If you want the top 3 on some attribute you could add `ORDER BY colName` before the `LIMIT 3`.

Comment: But this will ONLY return style 7, I want all the different styles, but only a max of 3 for each.

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't get that from the original question. Sorry if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the LIMIT syntax [here](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Because of your version of MySQL, your options may be quite limited; it may be impossible to do this in a single query, so I figured I'd give an alternative.

A simple solution would be to iterate over each style and query that style with a LIMIT 3 parameter, but you would have to execute a lot of queries. To combine these into a single query, first get a list of all the styles:

```
SELECT DISTINCT style_number FROM styles;
```

Then you can then iterate over the style_numbers to build the SQL string in your programming language so that it reads as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM styles WHERE style_number = 'style 7' LIMIT 3
UNION
SELECT * FROM styles WHERE style_number = 'style 8' LIMIT 3
UNION
...
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

The TOP clause allows us to specify how many rows to return.

For example: SELECT TOP 3 * FROM table WHERE style_number = "style 7"

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Comment: There is no `TOP 3` thing in mysql. Use `LIMIT` instead of it