# mysql - selecting limited rows of duplicate columns

Tags: mysql, limit

#### What I have

So I'm running this statement:

```
SELECT
  i.id,
  i.item_id,
  v.item_to_map_id,
  i.date,
  COALESCE( SUM(CAST(CAST(v.score AS char) AS SIGNED)), 0 ) AS score
FROM item_to_map i
LEFT JOIN
  vote_item v
    ON i.id = v.item_to_map_id
GROUP BY
  i.id, i.item_id, i.date, v.item_to_map_id
ORDER BY
  item_id asc, score desc;
```

And I'm getting the following table:

```
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+-------+
| id | item_id | item_to_map_id | date                | score |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+-------+
|  1 |       1 |              1 | 2017-07-05 09:38:23 |     3 |
|  3 |       1 |              3 | 2017-07-05 09:38:23 |     0 |
|  2 |       1 |              2 | 2017-07-05 09:38:23 |    -1 |
|  4 |       2 |           NULL | 2017-07-05 09:38:23 |     0 |
|  5 |       2 |           NULL | 2017-07-05 09:38:23 |     0 |
|  6 |       2 |           NULL | 2017-07-05 09:38:24 |     0 |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+-------+
```

What I'm trying to do is select the first X of the repeated `item_id`s based on some ordering, for example, score or date.

### What I've tried

I looked at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1902167/6554121 and tried a modified version:

```
SELECT
  i.id,
  i.item_id,
  v.item_to_map_id,
  i.date,
  COALESCE( SUM(CAST(CAST(v.score AS char) AS SIGNED)), 0 ) AS score
FROM item_to_map i
LEFT JOIN
  vote_item v
    ON i.id = v.item_to_map_id
WHERE
     (
          SELECT
               COUNT(*)
          FROM
               item_to_map i2
          WHERE
               i2.item_id = i.item_id
     ) < 3    
GROUP BY
 i.id, i.item_id, i.date, v.item_to_map_id
ORDER BY item_id asc, score desc;
```

However this returns me no results

### What I expected

If ordered by score:

```
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+-------+
| id | item_id | item_to_map_id | date                | score |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+-------+
|  1 |       1 |              1 | 2017-07-05 09:38:23 |     3 |
|  3 |       1 |              3 | 2017-07-05 09:38:23 |     0 |
|  4 |       2 |           NULL | 2017-07-05 09:38:23 |     0 |
|  5 |       2 |           NULL | 2017-07-05 09:38:23 |     0 |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Have you tried add LIMIT 1 after the order by? You have ordered your data so you only need to cut the other data showing only one row, that is aciheved using LIMIT 1.

Comment: @GenaroMorales It's already returning me no results, I don't see how a limit would help.

Comment: I was seeing the first query you mentioned, before you added the second select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using session variables which simulate row number functionality:

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SET @item_id = 1;

SELECT t.id, t.item_id, t.item_to_map_id, t.date, t.score
FROM
(
    SELECT
        @row_number:=CASE WHEN @item_id = t.item_id
                          THEN @row_number + 1 ELSE 1 END AS rn,
        @item_id:=t.item_id AS item_id,
        t.id, t.item_to_map_id, t.date, t.score
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            i.id,
            i.item_id,
            v.item_to_map_id,
            i.date,
            COALESCE( SUM(CAST(CAST(v.score AS char) AS SIGNED)), 0 ) AS score
        FROM item_to_map i
        LEFT JOIN vote_item v
            ON i.id = v.item_to_map_id
        GROUP BY
            i.id, i.item_id, i.date, v.item_to_map_id
    ) t
    ORDER BY
        t.item_id, t.score DESC
) t
WHERE t.rn <= 2    -- this restricts to the first two rows per item_id group
                   -- as ordered by the logic in your ORDER BY clause
```

As far as I know, there is no nice way to get the first X records of a group in MySQL, unless your schema coincidentally happens to have row numbers already for each group.  Using session variables as above is one way to handle this, and the performance might even be good as well.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: It's returning me the correct number of rows, but the ordering is off. For `item_id` 1, I'm getting `id` 1 and 2, instead of 1 and 3

Comment: Give me the `ORDER BY` condition you want to use and I'll update my answer.  I just slightly modified your current query, leaving `ORDER BY` the same.

Comment: So there's really two order by conditions I'll be looking to use, Ordering by score while ordering by their item_id, ( as seen in the sub query -> `ORDER BY item_id, score DESC` ) and order by date -> `ORDER BY item_id, date DESC`. I hope this clear things up

Comment: This is really strange.  The current `ORDER BY` should already be working correctly.  You might want to check your data at this point.  Better yet, create a demo at [Rextester](http://www.rextester.com) and paste the link here.  I don't see anything wrong with my query.

Comment: As you can see in my full table, the score is `3` then `0` for `item_id` 1. But I'll try to make an example;

Comment: Well I have an example here http://rextester.com/FHK92704 but for some reason the scoring is all returning 0 when I run my select query.

Comment: Updated the link to reset auto increment http://rextester.com/OQUPK91863

Comment: @A.Lau The data in this demo does _not_ agree with what you posted in the above question.  The output my query gives is consistent with this data.  This is why I asked you to check your data.

Comment: The site's a little confusing for me I'll try to update it to provide the same result

Comment: @A.Lau Use `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS yourTable` at the very start of the script.  If you can give me the same data as above I can test my query against it.

Comment: @A.Lau I got to work by wrapping your original query as a subquery.  Not sure why this is necessary but in any case my answer should work for you now